# EdgeHubConnectionString and IOTEDGE_IOTHUBHOSTNAME are not set. Exiting

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning

**i am getting above error while deploying a model in azure aci**

my model deployment code is :

```
service=Webservice.deploy_from_model(name="test-pf-1",
                                deployment_config=aci_config,
                                models=[model],
                                image_config=image_config,
                                workspace=ws)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

i am tracing above log through

```
service.get_logs()
```

can anyone help me please